# Error with delete query

Tags: mysql

I used this query to delete roman & hindi colunn values from table.

```
DELETE s.hindi, s.roman from song s where name=X;
```

Error : `Unknown table 'hindi' in MULTIDELETE.`

Answer (score 6):

You don't delete column values, you can only delete entire rows.

The syntax for a `DELETE` query is

```
DELETE FROM table_name [ WHERE conditions ]
```

For example

```
DELETE FROM song WHERE name = 'X';
```

You can drop columns from a table though I'm not sure if that's what you want

```
ALTER TABLE song DROP COLUMN hindi, DROP COLUMN roman;
```

You can also update specific columns. If you want them empty and your design allows it, use `NULL`

```
UPDATE song SET hindi = NULL, roman = NULL WHERE name = 'X';
```

Comment: How can I delete column values..?

Comment: @Aditii You're going to have to explain what you mean. Try showing some expected "before" and "after" data. Edit your question to add more information, don't post it here in comments

Comment: You can't "delete" column values, you can only store a different value in the column. A value that means deleted, usually NULL.